# Force user to watch section of a video, then provide next button

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video, html5-video

Probably an odd question, but I am looking at a project whereby a user is asked a series of questions. One of the questions could be to watch a video, then make a next button appear to watch the next section of video.

Some of the users will have iPads so this rules out Flash I guess?

Any ideas what the best approach might be?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to support browser based playback in iOS; then you cannot use Flash.  However, if you need to support older browsers; then you may not be able to use HTML Video.  I'm not sure if you've given us enough information to help you choose a path.  And even so; this site is to help answer specific programming questions; not help you choose technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 video tag lets you track the playback location. You could use this to figure out when they have finished the video and then display the 'next' button. The tag can tell you how long the video is so you'll know when its done.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll let you know how it goes.